# Cannot run extensions in python scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

my craigscrap/extension.py is like this:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured

class SendEmail(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.frm = 'wrufesh@gmail.com'
        self.to = 'a@f.com, b@g.com'

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getbool('MYEXT_ENABLED'):
            raise NotConfigured
        ext = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.send_mail, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def send_mail(self, spider):
        spider.log("Are you getting the message?")
```

My settings is like this:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'craigscrap.extension.SendEmail': 80,
}
```

I was reading the documentation to impliment extension. I wrote this code for extension but it doesnot seem to run. As i expect this code to print

```
"Are you getting the message?"
```

when spider closes.
Plese help me to find my mistake.

Comment: I came to know that from_crawler method is never executed. So the signal is never caught. I assume i might be mistaken in setting extensions. Plz help

Comment: Offical [doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#sample-extension) did not clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my mistake. 
In settings.py add the following variables

```
MYEXT_ENABLED = True    

EXTENSIONS = {
'craigscrap.extension.SendEmail': 80,
}
```